# Crystal Report not opening in client computer

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on a windows application project that has some reports designed with crystal report. All works well including the reports on the development computer but if i installed the application on another computer, my reports will not open. 
I designed with crystal report version 13_0_22 using visual studio 2017. I downloaded crystal report run-time and installed on the client computer using this link (https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000628082019) i also tried setting the specific version of the crystal decision reference property to false, i tried installing other versions the crystal report run-time. 
This is my code:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand("PrintPV", myConnection);
cmdDataBase.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", pvParameters.EndDateValue);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", pvParameters.startDateValue);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pvno", pvParameters.PVNO);
adapter.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
SimpcaDataSet simpcaData = new SimpcaDataSet();
adapter.Fill(simpcaData, "PvFmiti");

ReportDocument myReport = new ReportDocument();
myReport.Load(@"C:\SIMPCA\Reports\pvNetFMITI.rpt");
```

then i copied the reports data to this "C:\SIMPCA\Reports\" directory on the client computer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, glad i solved the problem, it was refusing to open crystal report on client computer because i was building on AnyCPU platform/architecture while the runtime i downloaded was 64bit.